# Play and Stop an AVPlayer in a tableviewcell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My app Chat page is a table view and each cell AVPlayer with AVPlayerViewController The problem is I can click Play on multiple cells and they will all play simultaneously. I am trying to figure out how to pause the other cells when any Play button is clicked.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: dict1.voiceURL!)!)
avPlayer = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
avPlayer!.pause()
cell!.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
cell!.playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = true
cell!.playerViewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
cell!.playerViewController.player = avPlayer
cell!.playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.PlayerView_1.frame.size.width, height: cell!.PlayerView_1.frame.size.height)
cell!.playerViewController.player?.pause()
self.addChildViewController(cell!.playerViewController)
cell?.PlayerView_1.addSubview(cell!.playerViewController.view)
```

Please help as I am very new in this field. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare two variable which store last_selected & Current_Sellected indexPath like this

```
    var lastSelectedRow: IndexPath?
        var currentlySelectedRow: IndexPath?
        
            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourClass
            {
                cell.playVideo()
            }
            
            if let lastCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: lastSelectedRow) as? YourClass
            {
                lastCell.pauseVideo()
            }
    
                super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                lastSelectedRow = currentlySelectedRow
                currentlySelectedRow = indexPath

tableView.reloadRows(at: [lastSelectedRow], with: .automatic)

            }
```

Comment: When we click on the play button of the avplayer controller didSelectRowAt not called